# A different type of Gaussian Grassmann Integral

Tags: grassmann-numbers

Let $A$ be an antisymmetric matrix.

Usually, one proves that for a Grassmann integral of the type,
$$\int d\psi d\theta \exp( \psi^T A \theta) = \det(A)$$
where $\psi$ and $\theta$ are vectors of Grassmann variables.

I have a different problem which I feel should trivially reduce to the same, but it can't figure it out:

$$\int d\psi d\theta \exp( 1/2 \psi^T A \psi + 1/2 \theta^T A \theta)$$

I think it should be possible to show that my expression is equivalent to the upper one, but the necessary variable substitution escapes me.

Comment: The statement in the question(v1) would in general need the assumption that the matrix $A=-A^T$ is antisymmetric.

Comment: Ah, okay. I know the version below doesn't require this assumption because the symmetric part of $A$ gives 0 contribution to the Grassmann integral anyway

Comment: In the first Grassmann integral of the question(v1) the symmetric part of $A$ contributes non-trivially.

Comment: Okay. From this I take that I cannot transform the version 2 into version 1. But with the answer RE the Pfaffian that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second integral factors into the product of integrals over $\psi$ and $\theta$.  In your notation, you want to show that the $\int d\psi \mbox{exp}(1/2 \psi^TA \psi) = \mbox{Pfaff}(A)$, the [Pfaffian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian) of $A$.  Then use the fact that $\mbox{Pfaff}(A)^2 = \mbox{det}(A)$.

Comment: Ah, I think I already did that, I just had no clue what a Pfaffian was, and got stuck at proving Pfaff(A)^2 = det(A).

Comment: ...where the answer(v1) has implicitly used at one point that $A$ is antisymmetric, either in the definition of the Pfaffian, or in the very last equality...

Answer (score 2):

Define the Grassman variables $\sqrt{2}\eta=\psi+\phi$ and $\sqrt{2}\chi=\psi-\phi$.

Then
$$ \eta^{T} A \chi = {1\over 2} (\psi+\phi)^{T} A (\psi - \phi) = {1\over 2}(\psi^T A\psi - \phi^T A \phi)$$

Since the middle terms cancel by antisymmetry of A and the Grassmann property. The result proves the equality of the two actions, so that the determinant of A is equal to the product of Pfaffians.

This is not quite what you wanted--- there is a minus sign in the above. But the minus sign only gives an overall minus to the whole expression if the dimension of A is odd, and it is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. How about I define them as $\psi + i\phi$ and $\psi - i\phi$? Then, the middle terms should still cancel, but I'll get a $+$ sign. Also, for an antisymmetric matrix of odd dimension, the determinant is always 0, no?

Comment: @Lagerbaer: Yes, the "i" works in the action, but it changes the sign of the measure in the odd dimension case (because the $d\eta$ s get an "i" factor, so it is equivalent to what I did above.